# How do I get output into Java from a SELECT stored procedure in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle10g

I'm using Java to connect to an Oracle 10 Database.
I want to create a stored procedure (don't ask why) that takes no arguments
and returns a lot of rows. Specifically, in Java I want to be able to get this
data with something like:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("call getChildless");
```

where getChildless is the query:

```
SELECT objectid
FROM Object
WHERE objectid NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM subparts);
```

However, I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to get my
output from the stored procedure. I've googled it and I get
all this sample code that Oracle won't compile, presumably it's for a
previous version. Refcursors seem to come up a lot, but I'm not sure
if that's what I actually want, to use it with a ResultSet.

Comment: A ref cursor is definitely the way to pass a bunch of records into a ResultSet.  So I think the problem we need to solve is the failure to compile.  It would help a lot if you were to post (the smallest possible sliver of) your code and the compilation errors.

Comment: getChildless cannot be a query. It might be a procedure, function or view. How you might retrieve results from it depends on what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I presume Oracle JDBC is like MS-SQL JDBC...

```
while (rs.next())
{
    myint = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is dynamically typed, It does not make sense that it would not compile.
[See this link to the JDBC Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)